# How do I allow a twitter iframe with a content security policy (CSP)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, iframe, embed

When I add the meta tag I encounter this problem on chrome extension:

I encountered the following error: `"Refused to load the script 'https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: 'script-src 'self''. Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.`
I want it to work as a local extension in Google Chrome.

When I add iframe:

[image: error]

Iframe wasn't working, so I decided to use the embed code from publish.twitter.com instead. However, after copying the following:

```html
<a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/home"></a>
<script
  async
  src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"
  charset="utf-8"
></script>
```

Later i tried adding this meta but it didn't work either:

```html
<meta
  http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
  content="script-src 'self' https://platform.twitter.com;"
/>
```